# Why is the bonus for accepting answers excluded from the rep cap?

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-limit

I know that reputation gains from bounties and the accept**ed** answer bonus are excluded from the rep cap of 200 per day and can see why this makes sense.

But why is the +2 gained from accept**ing** an answer also excluded from the cap?  This makes less sense to me.

Comment: It wouldn't be fair to give answerers extra rewards without also doing the same for askers.

Comment: I'd think it's so that you accept answers naturally, rather than all at once when you need to push yourself up to the cap.

Answer (score 13):

**You** control when you accept an answer.

It makes little sense to make those `2` points count towards the cap, as it will result in strategic accepting.

Comment: True, also keep in mind there is limit on how many questions you can ask per day (6 maybe?) so the cap is very little anyway.

Answer (score 6):

What's the purpose of including accepting answers in the cap? If anything, you want to encourage people to accept answers whenever they can. Including this would only discourage people from accepting answers when they want.

The purpose of the cap is to keep power users from gaining too much reputation from older posts. Accepting answers is very unlikely to have that sort of reputation swing for any user.

Answer (score 3):

Both the +15 and +2 are for accepted answers; in the first case, the reputation is given to who answers, and in the second case, the reputation is given to who accepts the answer.

There is just one accepted answer per question; so, reputation from accepted answers cannot pile up as with reputation from votes. In such cases, it makes sense to exempt the reputation from accepted answer from the reputation cap, also because it is more probable that (generally) most of the reputation comes from votes.

I think that including the +2 in the reputation cap would be a bad idea, if that would cause users to wait accepting an answer for when they don't gain enough reputation, which could also be an excuse for not accepting answers.